# Intelij IDEA doesn't have Kotlin Native in Project Wizard

Tags: gradle, kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-native

I want to create Kotlin Native project using Intelij IDEA. According to [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/using-intellij-idea.html) this option should be under the Kotlin submenu in Project Wizard but for some reason I don't have it. Moreover it seems that I don't have gradle submenu, so I wonder if these two issues are connected.

Version of IDEA I use:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-193.6494.35, built on February 11, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.5+10-b520.38 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.4
```

[image: Project Wizard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why yours isn't working. Here is my Kotlin template list
[image: Kotlin template list]

Community version

[image: Intellij version]

The only possible issues I can think of are you have a very old Kotlin plugin, but I'm not sure how, or multiplatform is disabled for Windows, but that seems unlikely.

Update. From Windows. It's EAP 2020.1 version of Intellij, but I'm pretty sure 2019.3 would do the same.

[image]

Comment: I somehow messed up gradle I think. I deleted the cache of IDEA, and " | Gradle" options appeared on next launch.