# option to create a kotlin multiplatform project not present in idea 2019.3

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform

i want to create a kotlin mp project in intellij idea 2019.3 Community, but the options i see in new project window for kotlin are just jvm|idea and js|idea.

In several articles there are options like `mobile shared library | gradle`, present even for older versions oj IJIdea.

I already have kotlin in another project, as part of a maven project

any hints?

Comment: Possibly similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60430182/intelij-idea-doesnt-have-kotlin-native-in-project-wizard/60436412?noredirect=1#comment106934903_60436412

Comment: yes, looks exactly the same, with same idea version even.thanks - will try to delete the cache and report back

Comment: nope, cleaning caches+restart didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have latest **Kotlin** plugin installed and **Gradle** bundled plugin enabled.

See [these steps](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/mpp/multiplatform-library.html#creating-a-project) about creating Kotlin MPP project.

Comment: updated kotlin plugin to latest 1.3.71, checked that link and still do not see the option for multiplatform library.
only the first two options from the screenshot on that link.
gradle bundled plugin is also latest version

Answer (score 0):

gradle plugin was enabled, but still something smelled, so after some time spent enabling/disabling plugins, i decided to enable android support plugin - then after restart idea complained that `gradle-java` plugin is not enabled, after enabling that (from the error tab link, not the plugin management window in preferences) - the options to create various gradle projects appeared, including the ones for kotlin/multiplatform

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile plugin then restart the IDE